# DHTMLX Grid number filter is not working with zero (0) but working with zero as a string ('0')

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I am working with **DHTMLX Grid**, while implementing number filter in a column, it is working as expected. But it is not working if the field value is zero(0) and I am searching for zero (0).

**Observation:** If I put zero(0) in quotation (as string), it is working. It is not possible to change the API endpoint.

For example: If I put following as data for the default grid it is working for **hours** but not working for **cost**.

```
var data = [{
    project: "Real Estate",
    owner: "Louise Fisher",
    start_date: "02/03/2018",
    end_date: "06/05/2018",
    status: "Done",
    hours: '0',
    cost: 0,
    budget: 11768,
    balance: 8180,
}];
```

DHTMLX Grid code

```
var grid = new dhx.Grid("grid", {
        columns: [
            {
                width: 150,
                id: "project",
                header: [{ text: "Project" }, { content: "selectFilter" }],
            },
            {
                width: 150, id: "status", header: [{ text: "Status" }, { content: "selectFilter" }],
                editorType: "select",
                options: ["Done", "In Progress", "Not Started"]
            },
            { width: 150, id: "owner", header: [{ text: "Owner" }, { content: "inputFilter" }] },
            { width: 150, id: "hours", header: [{ text: "Number of hours" }, { content: "inputFilter" }] },
            { width: 150, id: "start_date", header: [{ text: "Calendar", colspan: 2 }, { text: "Start date" }], type: "date", dateFormat: "%d/%m/%Y" },
            { width: 150, id: "end_date", header: ["", { text: "End date" }], type: "date", dateFormat: "%d/%m/%Y" },

            { width: 150, id: "cost", header: [{ text: "Cost" }, { content: "inputFilter" }] },
            { width: 150, id: "budget", header: [{ text: "Budget" }, { content: "inputFilter" }] },
            { width: 150, id: "balance", header: [{ text: "Balance" }, { content: "inputFilter" }] },
        ],
        data: data,
        editing: true
    });
```

Comment: What is the column type defined under grid definition?

Comment: Hello @Viv I have updated the questions

Comment: Seems like a bug at their end; specially as they had a similar bug in previous versions (check: https://forum.dhtmlx.com/t/edn-column-type-does-not-display-zero-values-but-ron-does/17658). If you put values in double quotes then zero works otherwise not. I tried using column type but no gain there. Sorry, not much help here.